# SonarQube measurements for method related metrics

Tags: java, sonarqube

I would like to ask question about SonarQube (6.2) plugin development.

I have created plugin for measuring custom metrics and displaying the results of the measurements in a widget. Basic measurements are captured in class implementing `Sensor` interface. Derived metrics are calculated in class implementing `MeasureComputer` interface. Metrics collected by MeasureComputer are finally displayed in a widget as I mentioned above.

My only problem is that I have some metrics which are related to methods. So far I did not found a corresponding approach for that case.

Can you please advise me if it is possible or how it could be done differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest logical unit on which you can attach data (including measures) is the file. You can not save information at method level.

Still, you can save a measure of type "data", in which you will store structured information that you can reuse later on in a custom UI extension. You must just keep in mind that such information won't be available/displayed in any standard page of SonarQube - but only in your UI extension.